# Setting columns for an HTML template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<body onload="initialize()">

<div id="map" style="width:300px; height:300px; display:block;">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:300px; height:300px;"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"><br>
                <a href="{{ url_for('detail', site='MY1', days=1) }}">MY11</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href="{{ url_for('detail', site='MY1', days=1) }}">MY11</a>
                <select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value=""></option>
                    <option value="{{ url_for('detail', site='MY1', days=2) }}">48 hours</option>
                    <option value="{{ url_for('detail', site='MY1', days=3) }}">72 hours</option>
                    <option value="{{ url_for('detail', site='MY1', days=5) }}">5 days</option>
                    <option value="{{ url_for('detail', site='MY1', days=7)  }}">7 days</option>
                    </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
                <form>
                    <select name="mapchange"      onchange="updateMap(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                        <option  value="school1">school 1</option>
                        <option  value="school2">school 2</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using the above HTML code and I want to position my google maps image on the right-hand side of the page. I am using Bootstrap css styling which should have a default of 12 units, so would have thought the map should be set to the right of the page by the following code:

```
<div class="col-md-7"><br>
```

This is the rendered output:
[image]

What do I need to do or change to position it on the right?

Comment: Where does this div `<div class="col-md-7"><br>` end?

Comment: It ends soon after, I forgot to include in the above post: </select>  </form>   </script>     </div>

Comment: Just create the rest of the 12partial divs. <div class="col-md-5">Something</div><div class="col-md-7"> your code </div>.

Comment: @Roy The recommended way to do this is through using the offset classes. See [Johannes' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42724206/3136474).

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="map" class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-5 text-right">
                <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:300px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><br>
                <a href="{{ url_for('detail', site='MY1', days=1) }}">MY11</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href="{{ url_for('detail', site='MY1', days=1) }}">MY11</a>
                <select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value=""></option>
                    <option value="{{ url_for('detail', site='MY1', days=2) }}">48 hours</option>
                    <option value="{{ url_for('detail', site='MY1', days=3) }}">72 hours</option>
                    <option value="{{ url_for('detail', site='MY1', days=5) }}">5 days</option>
                    <option value="{{ url_for('detail', site='MY1', days=7)  }}">7 days</option>
                    </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7 text-right">
                <form>
                    <select name="mapchange"  onchange="updateMap(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                        <option  value="school1">school 1</option>
                        <option  value="school2">school 2</option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            <div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the rendered output

Comment: try setting your map width to 100%. You can also put it in the container like this: <div class="container-fluid"> <div class="row"><div id="map" class="col-md-12" style="width:100%; height:300px; display:block;"><div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:300px;"></div></div>

Answer (score 1):

Add `.col-md-offset-5` as an additional class to that element to move it to the right (by 5 grid units):

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-5 text-right">
```